# In XML parsing, what are the names of the characters that denote the beginning and end of a tag?

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing

A bit of background. I'm writing a parser for a templating language which is a subset of XML. The reasons I'm writing my own instead of using an existing parser are real, but not worth going into here.

My parser iterates through the characters in a string and switches mode when it detects the start of a new tag, the closing of an existing one, etc (it's a finite state machine, basically).

What I want to know is what name to give to the constants which store the tag opener, tag closer and terminating slash characters. (I know I just named them there, but I'm unhappy with these names)

So for this:

`<MyTag attr="foo" />`

What do you actually call the following characters (in the context of parsing):

- `<`
- `>`
- `/`

I especially have a problem with "tag closer" because that's really ambiguous, does it mean things like `</MyTag>` or does it refer to the terminating `/` or the `>`. See what I mean? I want to name everything unambiguously.

---

To clarify: I know what those characters are called, I'm actually after verbs which describe what those characters trigger the parser to do, not what the names of the characters actually are. Suppose the language were actually written like this: `[Mytag attr=/foo/ #]`. It's the same language, just different characters triggering the mode switch.

Comment: The obvious place to look would be in the XML spec, but below the level of [Start-Tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#dt-stag) the characters aren't explicitly named in the grammar. So just use whatever character names you're used to using for such characters (e.g. the third would usually (for me) just be "Forward Slash")

Comment: Thanks for the clue @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I'm sure there's an answer and this looks like a reasonable place to start looking.

Answer (score 4):

The `<` and `>` characters are called [angle brackets or chevrons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Angle_brackets_or_chevrons_.E2.9F.A8_.E2.9F.A9). The `/` character is called the [forward slash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//). I would just use those names, as they are unambiguous.

Comment: Yep, I know that, but what character they represent `<`,`>` or `/` is largely irrelevant to the logic. I'm actually after verbs which describe what those characters trigger the parser to do, not what the names of the characters actually are. Suppose the language were actually written like this: `[Mytag attr=/foo/ #]`. It's the same language, just different characters triggering the mode switch.

Comment: @IainFraser - I think you might be trying to abstract too much - `<`, for instance, can be the start of an element, a processing instruction or a document type declaration. Probably why it's not given a name in the XML spec - it's part of several different logical constructs.

Comment: @IainFraser: I understand what you mean, but do you honestly think that there will ever be different characters used in these instances? If that would happen, you'd have bigger things to worry about than the names of a few constants.

Comment: Well, no, but I was trying to illustrate the separation between syntax and logic that I was talking about. Like, suppose I were creating a generic parser (an abstract class, for instance) and there were certain tokens it had to look out for that were clues that it needed to mode-switch. In this implementation, it's `<`, `>` and `/`, but they could be anything really. I guess what I'm asking is academic more than anything else. It comes from wanting to know more about parsing and FSMs generally.